# AfterClose event in jquery fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a div that contains `<img />` tags. All images are clickable. I want to know which image (id) were clicked when `afterClose` event fired.

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo so that you can get better answers.

Comment: When you say "clickable" do you mean something like `<a class="fancybox" href="image01.jpg"><img src={image}" id="image01" /></a>` ?

Answer (score 0):

put this in the afterClose event as part of that function 
 `$('#id of div that contains images').click(function(){var clickedwhat = $(this).val();});`
make .val() something thats useful about the image so maybe .html()

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').find('img').each(function(i,e){
  $e = $(e);
  $e.on("click",function(){
    alert( $e.attr('id') );
  }
});
```